# Prettier moves paren in setState, triggers no-sequence. How can I improve setState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, prettier

I'm trying Prettier on a React/TS project. I have an issue with setState and how Prettier moves a parenthesis.

This is the state in one of my components:

```
type State = {
  isEdit: boolean;
  model: PaymentMethodModel;
}
```

I'm using the following code to update state.

```
this.setState(
  (state) => ((state.model.paymentMethod = paymentMethod, state)),
  this.updateValidation
);
```

Prettier changes this to:
(Note the moved end paren after state.)

```
    this.setState(state => ((state.model.paymentMethod = paymentMethod), state), this.updateValidation);
```

After prettier changes the code, this triggers `no-sequences`.
It seems there is no way to change the behaviour of Prettier.
Previously i updated the state with the `...` operator, but that way I lost the typing.

Is the following a reasonable solution?

```
this.setState(
  (state) => (): State => {
    state.model.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    return state;
  },
  this.updateValidation
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before talking about the code styling, there's something else about your example you should be aware of.

Mutating the state is going to give you some issues with your component not always re-rendering when you need it to.

You should always return a new object representing the next state:

```js
this.setState(
  (state) => ({
    model: {
      ...model,
      paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
    }
  }),
  this.updateValidation
);
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: Unrelated to the question, if you're using react >= 16, you should consider using hooks instead. They would allow you to add some modularity to your state.

Comment: I did use that way previously, but the problem is that the typing is lost. Thing is that I want that model object (or a deep copy) intact.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the typing doesn't get lost in this approach, `#setState` understands that the properties you pass as an update are a subset of the full state. See the type definition: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9f8ff98dd1abb590654a7c75aaf26c09e25732dc/types/react/index.d.ts#L485-L491

Comment: I guess it's the three dots that creates an {object, like, this} of the PaymentMethodModel class object.

Comment: That's right, that's the spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax